# Cannot remove .droppable functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a bunch of DIV's that I'm using to allow a user to drop other DIV's onto. This will be a "Fill in the Blank" kinda thing. With the droppable being the blank in the sentence and the droppable being the answers they can choose from.

The issue I'm having at the minute is currently when they drop their answer div onto the droppable div, my function removes the draggable from the draggable element, but the droppable element remains able to have more divs dropped onto it.

I was wondering how can I get this to disable the droppable div, so that once an "answer" is dropped onto it's the only thing that can be.

Here's what my function looks like currently:

```
function handleCardDropOne(event, ui) {
  var cardValue = ui.draggable.attr('id');

  ui.draggable('disable');
  $(this).droppable('disable');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'});
  ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
};
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle replicating your issue for faster solution

Comment: Use the 'drop' event of the droppable widget. `$("#droppable").droppable({drop : function(){ $(this).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ) }});`  http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-disabled  http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    //Drag 1
    $( "#draggable" )
    .draggable({ snap: "#snap-one", snapMode: "inner", snapTolerance: 5 });
    //Drag 2
    $( "#draggable2" )
    .draggable({ snap: "#snap-two", snapMode: "inner", snapTolerance: 5 });  
    //Drop 1
    $( "#snap-one" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var top = $('#draggable').css('top')
        ,left = $('#draggable').css('left');
            if (top === '-107px'){
                if(left === '0px'){
                    $(ui.draggable).draggable('disable');
                    if ($('#draggable').hasClass('ui-draggable-disabled')){
                    alert('hello');
                    }
                }
            }
      }
    });
    //Drop 2
    $( "#snap-two" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable2",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var top = $('#draggable2').css('top')
        ,left = $('#draggable2').css('left');
            if (top === '-107px'){
                if(left === '0px'){
                    $(ui.draggable).draggable('disable');

                }
            }
      }
    });

});
```

```css
.draggable { 
    width: 80px; 
    height: 80px; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0; 
    font-size: .9em; 
}

.snap { 
    width: 80px; 
    height: 80px; 
    margin: 0 10px 25px 0; 
    float:left;
}
.ui-state-highlight{
    background-color:yellow;
    color:#000;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="snap-one" class="snap ui-widget-header" style="background: #ffc36a;">AAA</div>
<div id="snap-two" class="snap ui-widget-header" style="background: #ffc36a;">BBB</div>

<div class="demo">
    <br clear="both" />
    
    <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content" style="background: #a7fbdf;">
        <p>AAA</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content" style="background: #a7fbdf;">
        <p>BBB</p>
    </div>
</div>
```